Error: Error waiting for instance to create: required iam.serviceAccountUser role on the service account
Hi When i try to create a instance in GCP i am getting issue with the user role where the error message is given below. I am getting same error for another instance creation process. Even i mapped the right role to the user to access the service account i am getting the same issue.

Error: Error waiting for instance to create: The user does not have access to service account 'squidsit-squid-sit@igd-poc-417106.iam.gserviceaccount.com'. Use: 'brahatheeswaran.parimalam@abcdefg.com.au'. Ask a project owner to grant you the iam.serviceAccountUser role on the service account.
with module.zkevm_full.google_compute_instance.squidproxy[0],
on ../modules/zkevm/instance.tf line 157, in resource "google_compute_instance" "squidproxy":
157: resource "google_compute_instance" "squidproxy" {.
Error: Error waiting for instance to create: The user does not have access to service account 'bastion-fork-7-sit@igd-poc-417106.iam.gserviceaccount.com'. Use: 'brahatheeswaran.parimalam@abcdefg.com.au'. Ask a project owner to grant you the iam.serviceAccountUser role on the service account.
with module.zkevm_full.google_compute_instance.bastion,
on ../modules/zkevm/instance.tf line 194, in resource "google_compute_instance" "bastion":
194: resource "google_compute_instance" "bastion" {.




I tried adding the user role to the user - brahatheeswaran.parimalam@abcdefg.com.au so that he is able to create instance by accessing service account.

The error is clear albeit cryptic.
Service Accounts are both identities and resources.
In this case, your user identity (brahatheeswaran.parimalam@abcdefg.com.au) needs to be given permission to use the two Service Accounts (treated as resources) by someone (in your org|project) who has permission (you can't do this using this user|email account) to grant your account this role:

squidsit-squid-sit@igd-poc-417106.iam.gserviceaccount.com
bastion-fork-7-sit@igd-poc-417106.iam.gserviceaccount.com)

It is likely that, rather than grant the role to your user account directly, your user account will be added to existing group(s) that confer this role upon it.
EMAIL="brahatheeswaran.parimalam@abcdefg.com.au"

ACCOUNTS=(
  "squidsit-squid-sit@igd-poc-417106.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
  "bastion-fork-7-sit@igd-poc-417106.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
)

for ACCOUNT in "${ACCOUNTS[@]}"
do
  gcloud iam service-accounts add-iam-policy-binding \
  ${ACCOUNT} \
  --member="user:${EMAIL}" \
  --role="roles/iam.serviceAccountUser"
done


Short:
Please, check that you open IAM page for the right project.
Long:
To me your screenshots shows that you gave all rights needed. But for me it looks strange that your project ID is igd-poc-417106 but the name in the "Inheritance" columns says "Polygon-test". My guess is that you are trying to create an instance in igd-poc-417106 but you opened IAM page for another project and set the permissions there.
